# How can I mount a network folder on osx so it appears as an optical drive?

Tags: macos, network-shares, samba

I have a bluray drive on a linux box that I have shared across the network via SAMBA. I can access this easily from my Macbook Pro but there is a program I have that won't access it because it will only open optical disks. Is there a way of mounting this folder in OSX so the drive appears as an optical drive to this program? (The program in question is makemkv)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to with the mount command.  The file system could be an optical type, but the URL or location would be your smb:// string.